# combining flex UI with native objective c into single ios application

Tags: ios, objective-c, apache-flex

I am running out of time can anyone suggest me a good solution for my problem

**Problem:**
I am working in a **ios project** in which they have a UI designed already in flex a year ago..Now I have done all the backend coding with objective-c using apple native (IDE) xcode ,Now i dont know how I am going to combine the flex UI with the backend Objective c coding to integrate into a single application.

Comment: I dnt think u can use the flex UI into native iOS development

Comment: yes you do, but its hard. see Adobe Native Extensions

Comment: @hpiOSCoder You can create a Native iOS Application in Flex using Adobe AIR.  And you can use something called Native Extensions to call Native iOS code from the Flex/Adobe AIR Application.  That said; I expect this will be difficult for large amounts of functionality.  The poster is probably better off re-creating their UI in Native iOS; or re-writing their 'backend code' in ActionScript.

Comment: With the amount of time this will take and the amount of reworking your Objective-C code will require for a Native Extension, you are likely better off rewriting one or the other into a single codebase as Reboog711 described. (I would also listen to his advice just on principle; he is the foremost expert on Flex on SO). Combining a large backend written natively with a Flex front-end will be difficult and probably not work as well as you would hope.

Comment: **Reboog711** and **Josh Janusch**:thanks for your suggestions but things have gone too far and i am at the final stage of implementing the project So,I think there wont be any way to get back off rewriting ,Can u please suggest me some sample tutorials or links addition to what **csomakk** has  given.

Comment: @Reboog711 thanks for the comment. I was not knowing this! :(

Comment: @user2549256 That is actually the problem here. There is very little documentation for combining AS3 with Native Code. And all the documentation out there is for simple things like changing the volume or accessing maps or creating an alert. Simply put, what you want has never been done before to my knowledge nor have I ever seen someone attempt to do it. ANEs are not meant for this.

Answer (score 1):

With Adobe Native Extensions you can do it, but I warn you, it'll be a hard game to get it start. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt1.html

Comment: ok csomakk i will check this and let u know.. thanks for your rply